# Returning a certain list structure in Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with list (and list of list, and list of list of lt...) structures.

Answer (score 1):

Use t the += instead of the .append() operator.
and use a second list temp

```
new_list = []
for sublist in lines:
    temp = []
    for word in sublist:
        temp+=key_to_phonemes[word]
    new_list.append(temp)
```

edit:

```
new_list = []
for n,sublist in enumerate(lines):
    new_list.append([])
    for word in sublist:
        new_list[n]+=key_to_phonemes[word]
```

is better as it saves you from making temp

endEdit

The behavioural difference here is as follows.

> [ 1 , 2 , 3 ].append( [ 4 , 5 ] )

```
[ 1 , 2 , 3 , [ 4 , 5 ] ]
```

Vs.

> [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]+[ 4 , 5 ]

```
[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ]
```

Comment: Good point could have used list addition instead of iterating over key_to_phonemes

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new list in your loop and collapse the key_to_phonemes:

```
new_list = []

for sublist in lines:
    sub = []
    for word in sublist:
        for phoneme in key_to_phonemes[word]:
            sub.append(phoneme)
    new_list.append(sub)
return new_list
```

You could also do this with a list comprehension:

```
return [[p for word in sublist for p in key_to_phonemes[word]] for sublist in lines]
```

Output:

```
>>> convert_to_phonemes([['THE', 'FIRST'], ['WITH', 'A']], key_to_phonemes)
[['DH', 'AH0', 'F', 'ER1', 'S', 'T'], ['W', 'IH1', 'DH', 'AH0']]
```

Comment: It will add duplicate for example with ['with','the'] It will give
['W', 'IH1', 'DH','DH', 'AH0']

Comment: It is giving this output [['W', 'IH1', 'DH'], ['DH', 'AH0']].. as it will just append a list it won't remove duplicates

Comment: for with it will give ['W', 'IH1', 'DH'] and for 'the' it will give ['DH', 'AH0']

Comment: Sorry that's right, I was using the OP's request `[['THE', 'FIRST'], ['WITH', 'A']]`, which returns the expected output... there is no mention of removing duplicates.

Comment: In this case duplicates don't arise but for a general case they may be there and OP is requesting a single list for list in lines and not list of list

Comment: Ahh, misunderstood the OP question will fix answer... but I still don't see the need to remove duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

```
for sublist in lines:
    new_list.append([])
    for word in sublist:
        x = set(key_to_phonemes[word])
        y = set(new_list[-1])
        y = list(x.union(y))
        new_list[-1] = y
return new_list
```

As for each sublist you are creating a new list.And then using set concept we are adding distinct key_to_phonemes to the last element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can done this using `list comprehension`

```
lines = [['THE', 'FIRST'], ['WITH', 'A']]
key_to_phonemes = {'WITH': ['W', 'IH1', 'DH'], 'THE': ['DH', 'AH0'], 'A': ['AH0'], 'FIRST': ['F', 'ER1', 'S', 'T']}

def convert_to_phonemes(lines, word_to_phonemes):
    return [[k for j in i for k in key_to_phonemes[j]] for i in lines]

>>>convert_to_phonemes(lines, word_to_phonemes)
[['DH', 'AH0', 'F', 'ER1', 'S', 'T'], ['W', 'IH1', 'DH', 'AH0']]
```